# Calculating distance in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, distance

I am trying to measure straight-line distance from residence to facility. I have both of these locations in latitude and longitude (degrees) in separate layers in shapefiles. These layers indicate which facility each resident went to. I have converted the projection to be UTM (meters). I am trying to measure distance in kilometers and am not sure how to do this. I cannot do a near feature because we cannot assume that all residents traveled to the nearest facility.

I calculated the the hypotenuse of a triangle through a function in excel and have the "distance" in a single number, but this is in degrees, so I am not sure if it can be converted to meters, or if the whole operation should be done differently.

Comment: Also, I would suggest editing your question to explain what your input data is in a bit more detail.  Do you have a point feature class/shapefile already, do you just have a table with a list of lat & long but not turned into a shapefile yet, or is it some other circumstance.  Understanding what your starting point is and as PolyGeo says above, what your goals are, is the only way we can help you.

Comment: I am trying to measure straight-line distance from residence to facility. I have both of these locations in latitude and longitude (degrees) in separate layers in shapefiles. These layers indicate which facility each resident went to. I have converted the projection to be UTM (meters). I am trying to measure distance in kilometers and am not sure how to do this. I cannot do a near feature because we cannot assume that all residents traveled to the nearest facility. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

if you join the facility layer to the resident layer using the facility id as the common field, you can create a new shapefile that has coordinates for both features in the table. then you can use the XY to line tool to generate a line from each residence to the facility it used. make sure to have the output set to a UTM projection. in the new line file, add a length field to the attribute table and calculate geometry.